# Generating Correlated Quasi Random Numbers

Tags: programming, simulations

Hi I am trying to generate correlated quasi random numbers using a sobol sequence in matlab. My Problem is the Following: Using "standard" random numbers it is easy to generate the 6 correlated random variables (NumberOfSteps X NumberOfSimulations) I need, using a cholesky decomposition:

```
L = chol(CorrelationMatrix,"lower");  
for i=1:NumberOfSimulations  
Z = L*randn(4,NumberOfSteps);  
for t=2:NumberOfSteps  
.....Z1(i,t);  
.....Z2(i,t);
```

Since i only want to generate the sequence once (very time consuming) the only way i found to generate two correlated r.v. is the following:

```
Ps = sobolset(NumberOfSteps);  
Ps = scramble(Ps,'MatousekAffineOwen');  
U = net(Ps,NumberOfSimulations);  
Z1 = norminv(U);  

Z2 = Rho.*Z1 + sqrt(1-Rho^2).*randn(NumberOfSimulations,NumberOfSteps);
```

Unfortunately I have No idea how I can extend this to 6 correlated random varibles. Can anyone help me?

Best regards, Alex